# Hybrid app development

Tags: javascript, cordova, firebase, firebase-authentication, html-framework-7

I am looking at building what is intended to be a very simple hybrid app and used on both iOS devices and Android devices. I have been looking at using framework7 for the framework and views and firebase 3.0 to handle the user authentication.
I am comfortable coming from a web background using Framework7 - or are there better alternatives?

Firebase seems to work to a degree for me with the authentication method of using email/password but I need 1 extra field but that is where I get stuck because the documentation and the firebase database leads me to believe I can only use email/password?

Any advise on this would be fantastic a this is something I have not had any experience with in the past.

[Password Authentication Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth)

[Framework7](https://framework7.io/)

I used Phonegap to see the app in action and it worked great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly, using firebase authentication you just have email and password. But in addition to authentication, firebase is a database! So you can store that extra field no database